# Currently running Azure Logic app instances referencing old key vault values

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault

so last night I updated an AAD client secret and it's value in the keyvault.

Now all the logic apps that were up and still running steps prior to the secret update appear to be holding the value of the old App secret and are returning: "BadRequest. Http request failed as there is an error getting AD OAuth token: 'AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID" in the steps where its trying to access the application that has the new secret.

To mitigate this I killed all the logic app runs and recreated new runs with the currently updated secret which are now working fine, but I was wondering if Microsoft had any sort of automated functionality one could build in to get the latest secret from the keyvault for instances like this where you change the value and you have running logic apps that are still using the old key vault values?

Or if there was any potential way I could configure the logic app to try to get the latest key vault value if it sees the bad request?

Update 12/12/2022:

Here's a shot of the logic app in question: [Logic app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkma9.png)

Comment: Is this standard or consumption?

Comment: If you were deploying your logic app, api connection and service principles using an infrastructure as code tool and a pipeline that is monitoring the expiration of the secret, a new deployment would have recreated the secret and applied it to the api connection, wouldn't have needed to do any manual work.

Comment: @Skin what do you mean by standard or consumption

Comment: @Mocas you're saying redeploying the logic app would potentially fix this? Would this kill all current running instances of the logic app

Comment: Fixing the problem with redeployment will depend on how are you creating your infrastructure. Would be yes if you are creating api connections, service principles, secrets all as part of pipeline(s) and connecting them without manual work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read the value inside the logic apps, to achieve your requirement you can use action from Key vault Connector called `Get secret` before HTTP action of yours. Below is the flow of my Logic app.

[image]

***RESULTS:***

*Before Updating the Value*

[image]

*After Updating the Value*

[image]

If you are using key vault secrets value for Api connection, then the best way to achieve your requirement is to redeploy the logic app with updated values, As suggested by @Mocas.

Comment: so I edited the OP to add an image of the logic app in question, I do have a similar setup to this, the issue is in that blanked out step right underneath SaveCurrentRequestRunLog I'm making a series of API calls that are waiting for a front end user input that uses webhooks to move the process forward. All the processes that were stuck in that step awaiting user input failed due to using the out of date keyvault value, and the only way to fix it was to cancel out the logic app and start a new run. In a case like that is there a way to build in a refresh system?